# Application form uk

Tags: uk, paperwork, applications

Can my brother ( my sponsor for a short term student UK visa) re-apply or just pay for my visa fees and  find me an appointment while I live in another country? Or can I apply where I am now and just send my brother link to pay the visa fees?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for your brother to complete the application and pay the fee online on your behalf. You are however responsible for the information stated in the application, so I recommend that before submitting it, he sends you a draft so that you can check the details are correct/true.

Comment: Thank you.Could I also apply by myself and send the link to my brother so he can pay?